# ag-grid can not move columns when having header groups

Tags: javascript, html, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid community version with plain JS. I have problem with moving columns to specified index when using header groups. Columns with header group are not moving programatically. However, I can move them with mouse drag. Is there a way to fix this?

I am using this line to move:

```
gridOptions.columnApi.moveColumns(['gold','silver','bronze','total'], 0);
```

Here's plunker demo with full example: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/lucyIRWiEK3ZumLGnAOr)

In my real example I will never pull apart columns from their groups and hence I can redefine all headers with specified order but it is not efficient.

Comment: How about `gridOptions.columnApi.moveColumns(['gold','silver','xd','xd2','total'], 0);`?

Comment: it works, but still not in all cases. I see the answer below and it can't be done as i imagine. I need to do it by setting new column defs

Comment: Can't you just write function to replace name of header column with names of children columns?

Comment: Unfortunatelty, no, the way my grid works is more complex and it would destroy other components, so i will add order to my headers and redefine them every time, I move columns manually. But thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read documentation:

> Moving Columns and Groups If you move columns so that columns in a
>   group are no longer adjacent, then the group will again be broken and
>   displayed as one or more groups in the grid.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in Column Moving section and couldn't find anything about groups.

Answer (score 1):

In your column definition, you can use an option called [marryChildren](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/#grouping-example-with-marrychildren-set).  This will keep the children together so that they cannot be moved outside of the group.

```
var columnDefs = [
    {field: 'athlete', width: 150},
    {field: 'age'},
    {field: 'country', width: 150},
    {field: 'year'},
    {field: 'date'},
    {field: 'sport'},
    {field: 'gold'},
    {field: 'silver'},
    {field: 'bronze', marryChildren: true,  children:[{field: 'xd'}, {field: 'xd2'}]},
    {field: 'total'}
];
```